# opencart domain migration error, Could not load template

Tags: opencart

I have a opencart eshop on my domain and its working fine. I tried to move the whole shop to other domain so I copied all the files and uploaded on the new domain. Changed the config files including the route, but I get this error

```
Notice: Error: Could not load template /data/web/virtuals/60000/virtual/www/catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/banner.tpl! in /data/web/virtuals/60000/virtual/www/system/engine/controller.php on line 70 Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /data/web/virtuals/60000/virtual/www/index.php on line 105
```

when I go to myeshop.com/admin, it starts to be really wierd. The admin login somehow shows (see pic below) but unable to login and these error show.

```
Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/www/top-yyy.cz/www/top-yyy.cz/vqmod/logs/Sun.log) is not within the allowed path(s): (/data/web/virtuals/60000/virtual) in /data/web/virtuals/60000/virtual/www/vqmod/vqmod.php on line 406Warning: file_put_contents(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/www/top-yyy.cz/www/top-yyy.cz/vqmod/logs/Sun.log) is not within the allowed path(s): (/data/web/virtuals/60000/virtual) in /data/web/virtuals/60000/virtual/www/vqmod/vqmod.php on line 415Warning: file_put_contents(/home/www/top-yyy.cz/www/top-yyy.cz/vqmod/logs/Sun.log): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /data/web/virtuals/60000/virtual/www/vqmod/vqmod.php on line 415LOG FILE COULD NOT BE WRITTEN
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSWDy.png

I had a feeling that some files might be missing or corrupted so I checked several times, but its seem like all files are fine. Can you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update the folder paths given in `config.php` and `admin/config.php` corresponding to the new server folder paths.
Also please make sure that your folder permissions are correct:

```
755 or 777 for image/
755 or 777 for image/cache/
755 or 777 for cache/
755 or 777 for download/
755 or 777 for config.php
755 or 777 for  admin/config.php
755 or 777 for  vqmod/
755 or 777 for  vqmod/vqcache/
755 or 777 for  vqmod/logs/
755 or 777 for  vqmod/modse.cache
```

If 0755 does not work try 0777.

Have a nice day !!